# Will using plugins slow down a CakePHP 2.0 app performance drastically?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Will using plugins like the one for Facebook connect by Webtechnick slow down performance drastically? If not, what will be the extent of damage to the speed of the application?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it yourself by implementing the plugin and comparing load speeds to when you haven't got the plugin loaded?

Comment: I have question for Oldskool and other guys, if you don't allow people to ask questions what is the purpose of stackoverflow, is this a platform for you experts only ?

Comment: If you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) you would have noticed this bit: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.". Every plugin is different and written by a 3rd party. Therefor there is no conclusive answer to a question like this and thus doesn't meet the requirements for questions that can be asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Oldskool said - it depends on the plugins you are including.

I can tell you from experience, that webtechnicks Facebook plugin does not create an excessive burden on the application.

However, other plugins that you may be including, might. Depending on how they hook in to your application, and what kinds of processing/queries are being executed, will all add up.

I would suggest installing the [CakePHP DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to analyze the performance of your application at a relatively high level. It gives you quite a bit of information, so check it out.

Hope this helps.